# What does 'void (*return_socket)(void *closure);' mean?

Tags: c, syntax, xcb

I am browsing though the XCB sources and I found this weird struct member:

```
void (*return_socket)(void *closure);
```

What does that mean? What's another way to write this?

Comment: It's a `pointer to a function`, requiring a function that requires a pointer to some data (although the doc or code will tell you what) as a parametre, and returning nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a **function pointer**.
It points to a function that returns `void` and receives a `void *` as parameter.

For example, you could use that as:

```
void myFunction(void *closure)
{
    printf("myFunction called with closure=%p", closure);
}

void (*return_socket)(void *closure) = myFunction;
```

Comment: I still don't quite get this notation. If `void` is the return value, and `void* closure` is the parameter, what is the bit in the middle? `(*return_socket)`.

Comment: `return_socket` is the variable name. Instead of an **identificator** as the function name, you use an **asterisk** and an **identificator** to indicate it's a function pointer.
You could assign to it later with `return_socket = myFunction2;`

Comment: Oh I see, the `*` is signifying it's a pointer. Would make more sense if the syntax was `void(void* closure)* return_socket` imo but oh well. I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: Your suggestion violates the language orthogonality

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'orthogonality'.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality_%28programming%29
How would you define a function pointer to a function that returns a function pointer and receives another function pointer as parameter? Using C's syntax, even if it gets complicated, the rule is the same for all cases, you read the type the same way despite if it's a function pointer or a primitive. `int *a` means `*a` is an `int`. As `void (*fcntPtr)(void *)` means `*fcntPtr` is a function. See how that works?

Comment: Doesn't that also apply in my case? `*return_socket` is a `void(void* closure)`.

Comment: No. You don't define `malloc` as `void *(size_t) malloc;`, do you? You define `void *malloc(size_t)`, right?

Comment: You just add the parentheses to indicate that the asterisk relates to the *function name*, making it a `function pointer`, not to the return value.

Comment: It's the presence of the parentheses enclosing the argument list that make it a function type. The parentheses around `return_socket` are not a part of the type, and only necessary to disambiguate the `*`. Maybe this is clearer:  `typedef void MyFuncT(void *);  MyFuncT *return_socket;`

Comment: C uses this "infix" notation for declaration and use. Your suggestion is logically consistent, it's just that C chose not to do it that way.  Same principle why we have `int a[10];` instead of `int[10] a;`.